# Auto formatting numeric string

Tags: c#, winforms, autoformatting

working with a c# windows form applications, I need to auto format my textBox value that means I want to make the last digit to zero before the decimal point, currently I am handling auto format to my text after to my decimal point using

```
double value;
if (double.TryParse(textBox1.Text, out value))
{
    textBox1.Text = String.Format("{0:0.##}", value);
}
```

this is working perfect, My problem is when I enter an example value "1257.00" It should be formatted as `1250.00`. Stuck here and made a full research but I couldn't find out the solutions, help me as soon as possible.

Comment: And if I enter 1257.57 what the result should be? Is it 1250.57 or 1250.00?

Comment: That should be 1250.00

Comment: How about? `double d = 1257.00;   d = d - d % 10;`

Comment: @user3021112 what is not working? `d` will be 1250 as you expect.

Comment: @L.B if u dont mind can u please explain me the logic

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have posted this quick and dirty solution (Console version, but the core logic will work the same in a WinForms application as well) and posted in this Fiddle:

https://dotnetfiddle.net/yvK9Ef

Salient points: You need to manually reduce the last digit before the "." to a zero. For that, what I am doing is to pick up everything except the last digit using the string Substring function and appending a zero. I agree this is not elegant but it works -- you alternatively could try the arithmetic way of dividing and modding until you get everything but the last digit.

```
    string number = "1257.00";
    double value = 0.00;
    if (double.TryParse(number, out value)) 
    {
        string roundedNumber = number.Substring(0, (number.IndexOf('.') > 0 ? number.IndexOf('.') : number.Length)-1) + "0";
        if (double.TryParse(roundedNumber, out value))
        {
            Console.WriteLine(String.Format("{0:0.##}", value));
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Error!");
        }
    }
    else
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Error!");
    }
```

Comment: No still the same it is not formatting in any way. I don't know where i made a mistake while rewriting this code to windows.

Comment: Could you post your code ? If you go to the link I provided above, you can change the value on Line #7 (value of "number" variable) and see the output changes as per what you have specified.

Comment: Yes that is working perfectly. Sorry for late I went outside, just now tried.